# What happened to the "newest question" feeds?

Tags: support, feed

I'm pretty sure I used to have an RSS feed called the "top questions" feed, or maybe it was called the "newest question" feed.  But I can't seem to find a link to any feeds anymore when I click on the Questions tab.  It used to be at the bottom of the page.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

I do see a feed link at the bottom after I click on a tag, but I don't see any feed links when I'm looking at all questions sorted by newest, or votes, or popular, or featured.

Comment: Wish I have this too... "newest question" feeds... I want this on my site...

Answer (score 2):

There's a feed link at the bottom of the main page, to https://stackoverflow.com/feeds - which I suspect effectively works as a "newest questions" feed anyway.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't see that because I always click on the Questions tab and there are no feeds links under any of the subtabs there.

Comment: When I add this feed to my reader, it is titled "Top Questions" and it looks nothing like any of the lists of questions under NEWEST, FEATURED, HOT, VOTES, or ACTIVE.  So I don't know what Top Questions really means, but it doesn't appear to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hmmm... when I looked it definitely looked like the "newest" feed - but that could have been coincidence.